# periodic data move from local server to remote server

Tags: postgresql, migration, archive

I have a local PostgreSQL server that is recording data on a solid state drive of less than 8 GB free space on a Windows 7 embedded 32 bit machine. In order to make a backup and store large data I need to setup a procedure to move my data at predefined intervals to a remote PostgreSQL server. I need to create a procedure to

1. connect
2. copy data to remote
3. confirm the copy
4. delete local
5. and then wait for next hour

Can someone guide me with the procedure? I am new to DB and server management. So would appreciate simple steps to achieve this.

Both servers run PostgreSQL, the DBs have the same table structures.